# Cannot connect to Azure websites ftp server

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been publishing my website to Windows Azure via ftp for months.  All of a sudden today it is refusing my username/password, from both Visual Studio and an ftp client.  I have reset my password in the Azure portal, but it's still not working.  I am 100% my credentials are correct.  Is anyone else currently experiencing this problem with Windows Azure websites?

Comment: hey, yes, i've just started experiencing the same as of yesterday. it happened around same time as they brought in the "Manage subscriptions/directory" functionality. I can still log into the websites on one directory, but not the ones in another.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right, i don't know how to get it to work with the normal deployment credentials, but if you just download the publish profile and open it in a text editor you'll find both a username and password - neither of which match what you entered in deployment dialog, or the username displayed on the page!

Anyway, its good enough to get you access!

Comment: Nice one Richard, good find.  seemed to get around it for me too.  Thanks heaps!

Comment: Thank you SOOO MUCH! I've been struggling with this for months! (And yes, the issue is still there.)

Comment: It is really incredible that four years later this issue is not yet fixed in Azure. All documentation points to create your own credentials, but then the only working ones are autogenerated. We are lucky this guy found a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: Servicedashboard Windows Azure at http://www.windowsazure.com/nl-nl/support/service-dashboard/

> **30 Oct 2013 7:00 PM UTC**
>    We are aware of an issue being reported regarding Windows Azure Web Sites FTP data access. We are responding to this issue with the highest level of priority. Further updates will be published to keep you apprised of the impact. We apologize for any inconvenience this causes our customers.
>
> **Last update:**
>    We are narrowing in on the issue with full engineering engagement. Web Site customers are advised to publish content using Web Deploy or Git which are fully functional. For details on using these methods, visit Azure.com and search for "Websites with Webmatrix" or "Publishing with Git". We apologize for any inconvenience this causes our customers and will provide an update at 2pm UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I found my org's IT department disabled FTP access for the site!

See for details:
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/10/securing-data-plane-access.html

All FTP was failing. WebDeploy was failing with 401, despite me having correct username and password from the publish profile.

The only way I figured out this was happening was via a warning message in the portal here:
[image]